# How to create Requests with url with square brackets in Scrapy?

Tags: python, http, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a page which start url would be

```
'http:listado.example.com.ar/ARTICLE#D[A:ARTICLE]'
```

where ARTICLE is an argument for the spider call.
The problem is that when I run my spider, I get 111 Connection Refused from the server. Looking to the scrapy's logs, I saw the next:

```
2015-12-08 17:50:06 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http:listado.example.com.ar/guitarra#D%5BA:guitarra%5D> (failed 1 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

It comes out that the request sent by the spider change the chars '[' and ']' for '%5B' and '%5D' respectively.

Inquiring into the start_request method, I found that the Request instantiation changes the characters. This is my overridden start_request:

```
 def start_requests(self):
    dareq = Request(url='http:listado.example.com.ar/%s#D[A:%s]' % (self.article_name,self.article_name), callback=self.parse_entry)
    self.logger.info('REQUEST TO: %s' % dareq.url)
    yield dareq
```

Running the spider I get the next log:

```
2015-12-08 17:50:06 [merclib] INFO: REQUEST TO: http:listado.example.com.ar/guitarra#D%5BA:guitarra%5D
```

Using the replace method won't work, and the field dareq.url is read-only, so it can't be fixed modifying the field manually.

How can I create a Request that effectively sends the ulr with those square brackets correctly?

Answer (score 0):

google for "**percent-encoding**".
It is not allowed to have square brackets in the url, so the Request method automatically encodes your url.

Comment: The problem with the automatic encoding is that the server waits for a GET http:listado.example.com.ar/guitarra#D{A:guitarra], but it gets http:listado.example.com.ar/guitarra#D%5BA:guitarra%5D. The server is never decoding the url, so it gets a not existing url requested

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'ARTICLE#D[A:ARTICLE]'
url = urllib.quote(url)
```

then you can `urlparse.urljoin(example_url, url)`